# Can hbm.xml file and hibernate annotations work together?

Tags: hibernate

When I am declaring named query via annotations Hibernate Session is not able to find it but when I put into hbm.xml it works fine.

It is a legacy system where all the hibernate entities are defined via hbm.xml and I am slowly trying to migrate it to annotations.

```
Is it possible to distribute hibernate metadata via both hbm.xml and annotations?
```

Exception is

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: queryName
```

Entity Class is

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({

    @NamedQuery(name="queryName", queryString="from Product pro")
})

public class Product extends HibernateEntity
```

Getting the Session

```
        SessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory = (SessionFactory) hibernateSessionFactories.get(targetDB);

        if (hibernateSessionFactory != null) 
        {
            session = hibernateSessionFactory.openSession(new HibernateEntityDifferenceInterceptor());

            session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
        }
```

Comment: It's useful to see how you configure SessionFactory.

Comment: Update with SessionFactory code

Comment: There is still no code that creates `SessionFactory`.

Comment: With new finding I realized that issue with mixing Annotation and hbm.xml for the same entity class. I guess Hibernate doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Spring support it's [definitely possible](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?78374-Hibernate-using-a-hybrid-annotation-and-XML-config-approach), so if you don't use Spring, you can look at the sources inside of it and figure out how it was implemented there.

Comment: Is it possible to configure SessionFactory using Spring just for Annotation and leave hbm.xml configuration as it is?

Comment: Nupe, that would mean you'll create several `SessionFactories`. But you need one that sees both XML files for some entities and annotations for other entities.

Comment: As my application is a Legacy System it would be very hard for me to move the logic to create sessionfactories. Is there any other work for this issu?

Comment: Did you take a look at how it is implemented in Spring? Also I personally consider XML as a much better way of Hibernate mapping than annotations, but this is a holywar topic.